# yii2 adding property in runtime

Tags: yii, properties

trying to add property to my AR model dinamically for my CRM system.

```
public function getCustomFields($key = null)
{
    if (static::$customFields === null)
    {
        $fields = (new Query)->from('client_fields')->indexBy('key')->all(static::$conn);

        if ($columns = static::$conn->getSchema()->getTableSchema('client_profiles')->getColumnNames())
        {
            foreach ($columns as $column)
            {
                if (isset($fields[$column]))
                {
                    static::$customFields[$column]['name'] = $fields[$column]['name'];
                    static::$customFields[$column]['settings'] = @json_decode($fields[$column]['settings'], true);
                }

                if( ! isset($this->{$column}))
                {
                    $this->{$column} = null;
                }
            }
        }

        static::$customFields = static::$customFields ?: [];
    }

    return $key ? (isset(static::$customFields[$key]) ? static::$customFields[$key] : null) : static::$customFields;
}
```

And here is the result:

```
Setting unknown property: common\modules\crm\models\CrmClient::user_id
```

Waiting for best solution to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Define all property in your model first, When you create a model Gii you will see the property definition.

e.g

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_activity".
 *
 * @property integer $ua_id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $filename
 * @property integer $created_at
 *
 * @property User $user
 */
```